# how to create multiple column layout for webpage with FLEXBOX or CSS COLUMNS

Tags: flexbox

My current code:

```
<div id="container">

    <!-- Use the header area for the website name or logo -->
    <header>
        <h1>Working with Columns</h1>
    </header>

    <!-- Use the main area to add the main content of the webpage -->
    <main>
        
        <article>

            <section>
                <h3>CSS Grid Layout</h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
            </section>

            <section>
                <h3>CSS Columns</h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
            </section>

            <section>
                <h3>CSS Flexbox</h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
            </section>
            
        </article>
        
        <aside>
            <!-- Use the paragraph element below to summarize the method you used to create your columns. Identify the resource you used and include a link to the resource that opens in a new tab. -->
            <p></p>
            
            <!-- Use the paragraph element below to note the resource you used to create your favicon. Include a link to the resource that opens in a new tab. -->
            <p></p>
        </aside>

    </main>

    <!-- Use the footer area to add webpage footer content ->
    <footer>
        <p>Designed by:  </p>
    </footer>

</div>
```

Any help? I can't get it to look like the first image. [Example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/msa9P.jpg)
vs
[How mine looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y32oo.png)

I've never coded before, but I'm having a hard time with this assignment.

How should I code it in the CSS file?

Comment: Code demonstrates no attempt to use flex box or css columns, and has a lot of unnecessary backslashes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In HTML, you must define each element. Let's not worry about the CSS just yet.

In the example image, let's count the different elements. We can easily see there are 2 big differences:

- 1x Header Element
- 3x Column Element

You are on the right track with using flexbox. The column elements will just be flexed and they will take their position on the page. However, in your code, you did not make the header a separate element.

Without seeing your CSS code, we don't know what other mistake there may be, however, I can provide you with my code.

```html
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <header>
            <h1>Working with Columns</h1>
        </header>
    </div>

    <main>
        <article>
            <section>
                <h3>CSS Grid Layout</h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
            </section>

            <div class="vertical-line"></div>
            
            <section>
                <h3>CSS Columns</h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
            </section>

            <div class="vertical-line"></div>
            
            <section>
                <h3>CSS Flexbox</h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
            </section>
        </article>
    </main>


    <!-- CSS Below -->
    <style>
        body {
            margin: 0;
        }
    
        h1 {
            background-color: #628c45;
            margin: 0;
            text-align: center;
            padding: 20px;
        }
    
        article {
            display: flex;
        }
    
        article section {
            margin: 20px;
        }
    
        .vertical-line {
            background-color: #628c45;
            width: 1px;
            height: 675px;
            margin-top: 40px;
        }
    
    </style>
</body>
```

Disclaimer:
This code was just something I quickly put together for the purposes of showing the separate elements.
The line separation was just something I hardcoded. There is a better way to do it, but I will leave that to you.

[image: Quick build]

---

Remember when you code:
"The computer will *always* do exactly what you tell it to do."
When you run into a bug or something unexpected happens, step back and review your code.

Keep going! Do not treat this as a failure. With practice, you will get better.

---

Comment: Thank you so much! Are there any online courses or tips you could share? I want to be familiar with programming languages like Java, C#, and C++ since I will take them in the spring. Honestly, I'm a little worried about failing because I'm already falling behind in HTML and CSS since the files we need for the book are confusing.

Comment: Best tip in terms of self-learning is never spend money on a course. Youtube has a ton of video tutorials. You must practice coding consistently to get it down. I'm still rather a beginner, not a pro. 

Which language of Java, C#, C++ are you taking in the spring? For C++, I recommend https://learncpp.com. I will also be using it to learn it soon. FreeCodeCamp's videos are also helpful. 

In terms of HTML/CSS/JS stuff, I primarily use w3schools and MDN. I love w3schools for their online in-browser code sandbox. I've used it for a little bit of Java code testing as well, but it's not great

Comment: I will be taking all three for my associate degree... I get the hang of it, but I worry about failing the class and feel so rushed that I barely learn anything. I'll check the the webpage, thanks

Comment: It is generally not advised for students to attempt learning more than 2 programming languages at the same time. School is rushed, there is no doubt. When you overload your academics, you're more likely to not learn any of the languages, and possibly be even more overwhelmed. School *might* teach you just enough for you to start rolling and testing things out. The rest is in your hands to practice, learn, and explore.

Comment: I decided to drop C++ and take it for a fall instead. I will be doing Java and C#. I got a bit nervous. thanks for the tips i appreciate it :)

Comment: That's certainly better. Let me know how it goes!
 Good luck :)